# What is the best way to "listen" on a setter?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want a custom function called after the setter call. Do you have an idea ?
An ObjectProxy on variables with PROPERTY_CHANGE listener is the only way ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the setter a part of a class you have created, or an existing class?

Comment: The setter is a part of a class I have created.

Comment: why not call the function within the setter function?! I don't understand your problem... some code would help.

Answer (score 1):

Extend EventDispatcher from your class, then in your set method simply dispatch an event.

```
class MyClass extends EventDispatcher {
    public static const PROPERTY_CHANGED:String = "PROPERTY_CHANGED";

    private _foo:Number = 0;

    public function MyClass() { }

    // else where
    public function set foo(value:Number):void {
        _foo = value;
        dispatchEvent(new Event(PROPERTY_CHANGED));
    }


}
```

Comment: just posted your answer when I was about to submit mine ;)

Comment: @goliatone - sorry mate! I hate when that happens, it's a shame you can't split reputation from questions.

Comment: You better use the correct event then though: [mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/PropertyChangeEvent.html).

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer a mechanism that I think is a bit more declarative and clean:

```
[Bindable]
public class MyClass
{
    public var foo:Number;

    public function MyClass() {
        BindingUtils.bindSetter(whenFooIsSet, this, "foo");
    }

    private function whenFooIsSet(newValue:Number) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to note that this will only work if you are developing a flex application. Also for clarity [Bindable] defaults to = [Bindalbe(event="propertyChange")] : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html

Comment: @Stephen Bailey: Agreed, this only works in Flex... but this question was tagged with Flex.

Comment: Ahh yes *blush*. Pehaps for new developers browsing answers the line between pure AS3 and flex is burly since they use the FlexSDK - so perhaps it will still help someone.